# Get All Records with same IDs and initial IDs (second column) In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

On one of my project, I need to retrieve the latest version of a record from a table where the id maybe match with a second table called initial_id. Like this,

- id 1 AND initial_id NULL   // (same 1)
- id 2 AND initial_id 1   // (same 1)
- id 3 AND initial_id 1   // (same 1)
- id 4 AND initial_id 2   // (same1)
- id 5 AND initial_id 4   // (same 1)
- id 6 AND initial_id NULL   // (same 2)
- id 7 AND initial_id NULL   // (same 3)
- id 8 AND initial_id 7   // (same 3)

In this case, my SELECT (with some subquerys) should retrieve those records because they are the latest version on each of them:

- id 5 AND initial_id 4
- id 6 AND initial_id NULL
- id 8 AND initial_id 7

It is pretty easy to get the first three (id 1, id 2 AND id 3) because the initial_id are based on the first id but the other ones are harder...

Hope I'm clear enough.
Please help me out. Thanks !

**UPDATE**
This is my query so far:

`SELECT a.id from table_a a WHERE a.id = (SELECT aa.id from table_a aa WHERE aa.id = a.id OR aa.initial_id = a.id ORDER BY aa.id DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Please show us the query you have so far.  Your explanation does not make it clear as to why the records you show are the "latest version".  Perhaps seeing your query attempt will clarify this?

Comment: I updated my post. Thanks

Comment: OK, I think I see the logic now.  It's a parent / child type of hierarchy.  If this were MS SQL, it would be a good case for CTE.  I'm not sure what the equivalent is with MySQL.

Comment: Yes it's like a parent/child hierarchy